# Logrotate Create Mode

Tags: linux, mongodb, logrotate

I have a trouble with logrotate service in linux.
I have a logrotate config for mongodb log as below:

```
/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
{
   rotate 10
   daily
   dateext
   dateformat %Y-%m-%d-%s
   dateyesterday
   missingok
   create 644 mongodb mongodb
   delaycompress
   compress
   sharedscripts
   postrotate
     /bin/kill -SIGUSR1 $(pgrep mongod)
   endscript
}
```

As can be seen, I expect that mode of new mongodb file to be 644 but it is 600 and only the closed log file mode is 644.

`ls -l` command output:

```
total 640
-rw------- 1 mongodb mongodb  9822 May 29 19:42 mongod.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 mongodb mongodb     0 May 29 19:29 mongod.log.2022-05-29T14-59-01
```

I don't understand what problem is exactly.

Comment: I recommend you ask this question on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) and voted to close because I think that is the appropriate forum for your question.

Comment: You may put `chmod 644 /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log` after the `/bin/kill -SIGUSR1 ...` line

Answer (score 0):

By default mongod process create its log file with permissions set to 600 e.g. available for read/write only by the owning process.

Since mongod 3.6 you can set the parameter [honorSystemUmask](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/parameters/#param.honorSystemUmask) to true on startup to allow the new log files to be created with the default user's umask.

SInce mongod 4.4 you can use [processUmask](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/parameters/#mongodb-parameter-param.processUmask) to modify the default umask for your mongod process to custom umask.

Example:

```
   mongod --setParameter processUmask=137
```

In that case your log file will have the permission: 640

Explained:

777 – 137 = 640

Owner will have read/write(6) rights , group will have read only(4) rights and other users will not have any permissions(0) ...

To allow later other linux users to read the mongo log files you can just add them to the mongo group as follow:

```
 usermod -a -G <mongogroup> <userid>
```

To check if user is part of the mongo group:

```
 groups <userid>
```

Please, note the above parameters are not available for Windows operating system.

Comment: So to read mongo logs I have two choices; first change processUmask value, second add related user to mongo group, right?

Comment: you have only one choice : set processUmask and add your desired users to your process group that execute the mongod process , the second option is to set the umask for other users read/write then all other users will be able to read/write but this is insecure option and not recommended since everybody logging in the system will be able to read your logs  ...